# the attr information in str output and extracting the column names from array

Tags: r

I have an array, its str information and its values are given as follows, My question is that how to extract the column  names (here they are "dt, ds and rb" ) from x. Moreover, in the str information, the first line of `attr` output is `$:NULL`, what does it mean?

```
> str(x)
 num [1:120, 1:3] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "dt" "ds" "rb"

> x
               dt         ds       rb
    [1,]      NA       NA     NA
    [2,]      NA       NA     NA
    [3,]      NA       NA     NA
    [4,]      NA       NA     NA
    [5,]      NA       NA     NA
    [6,]      NA       NA     NA
```

Comment: `colnames(x)`. See the `?colnames` help page.

Comment: The NULL just means there are no row names, only column names.